# Some Bazaar packages are missing in Ubuntu 13.10 (especially bzr-svn)

Tags: package-management, gtk, 13.10, svn, bazaar

Yesterday I installed Bazaar on Ubuntu 13.10. I also installed Bazaar plugins I use but some plugins installation failed because of missing packages. In my case the missing packages were `bzr-svn` and `bzr-gtk`.

For `bzr-gtk` it is not a big problem since the `qbzr` package is still in saucy repositories.

But AFAIK there is not any alternative for `bzr-svn`, i.e. using Bazaar with Subversion (**NOT git** or other VCS). I know that git could be an intermediate step in a potential workaround (using both `bzr-git` and `git-svn`). I also know that the SVN project could be migrated from SVN to git (and then use `bzr-git`). But I want to avoid those two things if possible.

So my questions are : how to use Bazaar in Subversion projects on Ubuntu 13.10? Is there a way to have `bzr-svn` (and `bzr-gtk` too) on Ubuntu 13.10? Will `bzr-svn` (and `bzr-gtk` too) be back later in Ubuntu 13.10 repositories or in future Ubuntu versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bzr-svn and bzr-gtk were no longer maintained upstream nor are their packages in Debian/Ubuntu. For that reason the packages have been removed in Debian sid, and that removal has trickled down to Ubuntu 13.10.

There is nobody working on reintroducing these packages as far as I know, though it would be great if somebody stepped up.

It is still possible to manually install the plugins, but some functionality will be broken (svn 1.7 which is part of 13.10 has some behaviour changes compared to earlier versions).

```
 % apt-get install python-subvertpy
 % mkdir -p ~/.bazaar/plugins
 % bzr branch lp:bzr-svn ~/.bazaar/plugins/svn
 % bzr branch lp:bzr-gtk ~/.bazaar/plugins/gtk
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is sad for those so useful projects (especially `bzr-svn`). :-( Is there a possibility to get the packages from an older version (13.04 for example) and install them (manually?) on 13.10?

Comment: I've added some instructions to the answer. YMMV